# Query by n number of parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Roughly speaking, the USDA nutritional database is structured like this:

```
+---------+--------+
| food_id |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | butter |
|       2 | bacon  |
|       3 | eggs   |
+---------+--------+

+---------+-----------+----------------+
| food_id | per_100_g | description_id |
+---------+-----------+----------------+
|       1 |        20 |              1 |
|       1 |        10 |              2 |
|       2 |        30 |              1 |
|       2 |        70 |              2 |
|       3 |        10 |              1 |
|       3 |        80 |              2 |
+---------+-----------+----------------+

+----------------+-------------+
| description_id | description |
+----------------+-------------+
|              1 | fat         |
|              2 | protein     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

I'm new to writing SQL. I can write a join that combines all three tables and I can query based on a single parameter such as how much fat a food item has. But is there a way to query on both how much fat `per_100_g` and how much protein `per_100_g` a food has? I know this is a little subjective but I'm hoping to get a learn out of this. Thanks!

My database is postgres. Ideally it'd be a solution that could scale to n number of nutritional criteria and n number of combinations, so, for example, how much fat, protein and sodium a food has or how much vitamin c, k, and potassium - without having to write a few thousand variations of queries.

EDIT:

A sample query I wrote, but only finds singular nutritional data is this:

```
select des.long_desc
    from food_des des
    inner join nut_data fat
        on des.ndb_no = fat.ndb_no
    inner join nutr_def fat_des
        on fat.nutr_no = fat_des.nutr_no
    where (fat_des.tagname = 'FAT') and (fat.nutr_val < 10)
```

EDIT 2:

I'd expect results from a query with fat less than 30 and protein more than 10 to return this filtered result

```
+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
| food_id | name  | fat_value | protein_value |
+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
|       2 | bacon |        30 |            70 |
|       3 | eggs  |        10 |            80 |
+---------+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Sorry, see edit ^

Comment: Hint SUM ..LEFT JOIN..GROUP BY..HAVING

Comment: @motleydev - Can you add expected output.

Comment: @Prdp See the second edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to find food with multiple nutrients:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM foods f
INNER JOIN food_ingredients i
ON f.food_id = i.food_id
INNER JOIN descriptions d
ON i.description_id = d.description_id
GROUP BY f.food_id, f.NAME
HAVING sum(CASE WHEN d.description = 'FAT' THEN per_100_g ELSE 0 END) = 10
AND sum(CASE WHEN d.description = 'Protein' THEN per_100_g ELSE 0 END) = 20;
```

The `Having` part can be easily extended to support more filters.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. I don't know where your postgres abilities are, but do you know if you can write a procedure to return a singular condition and then combine multiple procedures to achieve the same result? I am trying to learn the most "sustainable" way to add flexibility to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
    f.name, 
    j.fat_per_100_g,
    j.protein_per_100_g
from 
    foods f
    inner join (
        select
            i.food_id,
            sum(case when d.description = 'fat' then
                i.per_100_g else null end) as fat_per_100_g,
            sum(case when d.description = 'protein' then
                i.per_100_g else null end) as protein_per_100_g
        from
            ingredients i
            inner join descriptions d
            on i.description_id = d.description_id
        group by
            i.food_id
        ) j
    on f.food_id = j.food_id
where
    j.fat_per_100_g < 30 and
    j.protein_per_100_g > 10
;

    name    | fat_per_100_g | protein_per_100_g 
------------+---------------+-------------------
 eggs       |            10 |                80
```

P.S. bacon has has 30 fat_per_100_g so it is not returned if fat has to be LESS than 30g.